# Creating a code based on a UML class diagram, giving me an error

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have a UML diagram and made this code.. did I correctly interpret it? I'm not sure about the class Weapon part. I've gotten advice that Weapon does not inherit Blacksmith.. [image]
Here's my code:

```
class Character:
    def __init__(self, namestring):
        self.name = namestring
        self.health = 100
        self.type = ''
    def __str__(self): #string operation
        return f"Name: {self.name}\nHealth: {self.health}\n Type: {self.type}"

class Blacksmith(Character):
    def __init__(self, weapon):
        super().__init__(name)
        super().__init__(health)
        self.weapon = weapon
        self.type = 'blacksmith'
        
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, name, Type, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.type = Type
        self.damage = damage
#testing the code
w = Weapon('stygius', 'stygian blade', 63)
b = Blacksmith("sword")
print(b)
```

I have this error

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-dc0ac5ca43ff> in <module>()
      1 #test class instantiation
      2 w = Weapon('stygius', 'stygian blade', 63)
----> 3 b = Blacksmith("sword")
      4 print(b)

<ipython-input-13-536a28d9bb79> in __init__(self, weapon)
      9 class Blacksmith(Character):
     10     def __init__(self, weapon):
---> 11         super().__init__(name)
     12         super().__init__(health)
     13         self.weapon = weapon

NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

Comment: Parameter names aside, I'd say that you have it. the `Blacksmith.__str__` method could benefit from removal of superfluous whitespace, e.g. `"Name: {} \nHealth: {} \nType: {}"`

Comment: @MichaelRuth hi! I updated the code removing the weapon from inheritance of blacksmith? and added `super().__init__(name)` but now i'm having an error.

Comment: The `Blacksmith.__init__` requires two arguments: `name` and `weapon` but you provide only `name` albeit a `Weapon`. Also, there is no inheritance regarding `Blacksmith` and `Weapon`, as there shouldn't be, i.e. `Blacksmith` is not a `Weapon`. Rather, the relationship is composition, i.e. the `Blacksmith` has a `Weapon`.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas i added the full error now

Comment: error shows problem with line `super().__init__(name)` because `name` is local variable and it doesn't exist in this function - it can't find it. This `name` has nothing to do with `self.name` created in `Character`.  The same problem you will have with `super().__init__(health)` because `health` is also local variable and it doesn't  exists. Other problem is how you use `super().__init__()` - it should be used only once and it will runs `Character.__init__(self, namestring)` which expect text for name, You should use ie. `super().__init__("James Bond")`

Comment: This is a pure Python coding error and has nothing to do with the UML